# 438 Object doesnt support this property or method MS Project and Excel Macro

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I have the following code in a VBA I am writing within MS Project which calls an Excel spread sheet. I've refrenced the v15 Runtime librays for Project, Excel and Officein that order.

When I run it fails to compile due to a error 438 Object doesnt support this property or method on the line

> strFileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename _

....etc.

Can any one suggest where to look as this seems to be correctly syntaxed to me.

```
Dim strFileToOpen As Variant

strFileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename _
    (Title:="Please choose a file to open", FileFilter:="Excel Files *.xls* (*.xls*),")
Workbooks.Open FileName:=strFileToOpen
'# Open Workbook
MsgBox strFileToOpen
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both Project and Excel have an Application object that can be referred to directly by the name "Application". As the macro is running in Project, an unqualified reference to `Application` will refer to Project's own [Application object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff865152.aspx).

The [GetOpenFilename method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff834966.aspx) is part of the Excel Application object and not the Project Application object. To call this method, you need to qualify the call with a reference to the Excel Application object, like this:

```
Dim xl As Excel.Application
Set xl = New Excel.Application
xl.Visible = True

Dim strFileToOpen As Variant

strFileToOpen = xl.GetOpenFilename _
    (Title:="Please choose a file to open", FileFilter:="Excel Files *.xls* (*.xls*),")
xl.Workbooks.Open FileName:=strFileToOpen
'# Open Workbook
MsgBox strFileToOpen
```